# which one is better for performance : One controller per page or many pages in one controller?

Tags: php, performance, apache, codeigniter

I just wanted some advice regarding the MVC way of doing things. I am using codeigniter and I was wondering if it's better for performance to have one controller per page for a web application or to have one controller for all the pages?

Comment: i will suggest you to go for one controller, easy to manage and update many controller means you are not using DRY.

Comment: Single responsibility principle.... if there's a lot of commonality between controllers, then extend from an abstract; but if you have different business logic in controllers then keep them separate

Comment: my question is about performance of application ,i.e loading time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Conceptually, the MVC asks you to request a single controller. However, in practice, we may need to get information from all over. So the answer to your question comes down to the design of your application.

In codeigniter, you can use the hmvc scheme to break your code structure into models.

You will still request one (main) controller, and that controller will decide to made requests to module controllers for their own processing.

If you are not using a modular approach, then you are 'forced' to use one controller per request, and get additional information for page rendering through model requests or libraries.

I suspect the modular approach will be a bit heavier on performance, because of additional levels of abstraction, multiple times as each controller is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

In my opition, you should use one controller for one logical entity. 
For example if you are making an online store you would make controllers:

- Cart controller with add/delete/update and other methods
- User    controller with register/login/logout and other methods
- Catalog    controller with view and blablabla methods

And some other stuff